# Assign number to each /dir result and ask for number input

Tags: batch-file

first post here. I'm working on a small script and one of its parts is to list all users of a chosen Computer in the network. I want to be able to select any of the users without having to write the whole name.

%PCNAME% was defined before on a user input.

```
/dir \\PCNAME\Users
```

This lists every user on the %PCNAME% as long as its in the Network.

**Example Output:**

```
29.12.2020  10:35    <DIR>          .
29.12.2020  10:35    <DIR>          ..
21.12.2020  12:42    <DIR>          Public
01.03.2021  08:02    <DIR>          User1
16.02.2021  15:21    <DIR>          User2
24.02.2021  13:14    <DIR>          User3
               0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               6 Verzeichnis(se), 178.603.126.784 Bytes frei
```

I would like to have it look something like this:

```
[1] 29.12.2020  10:35    <DIR>          .
[2] 29.12.2020  10:35    <DIR>          ..
[3] 21.12.2020  12:42    <DIR>          Public
[4] 01.03.2021  08:02    <DIR>          User1
[5] 16.02.2021  15:21    <DIR>          User2
[6] 24.02.2021  13:14    <DIR>          User3
```

Now I want to do a simple

```
set /p User="Number of the User: ":
```

So you just enter for example number 5 and User would then be "user2"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you're using the wrong command from the outset, I'd suggest you use `WMIC`, instead of `DIR`. e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:"MachineID" UserAccount Where "LocalAccount='TRUE'" Get Name`, _(obviously replacing the MachineID as necessary)_. You could probably further filter that list too by including other options, like for instance, `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:"MachineID" UserAccount Where "Disabled='FALSE' And LocalAccount='TRUE' And Status='OK'" Get Name`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't think of that. Still, I can't find out how I would assign a number to each line.

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir \users ^|find "<DIR>" ^|find /v " ." ^|find /v /n ""') DO ECHO %%b&FOR /f "delims=[]" %%c IN ("%%b") DO SET maxchoices=%%c
ECHO select 1..%maxchoices%
GOTO :EOF
```

the first filter allows only lines containing `<DIR>`, the second excludes lines containing  `.` and the third adds the [sequencenumber] to the line.

`maxchoices` is then set to the last sequencenumber.

(I used `\users` because that suits my test setup)

There are many articles on SO about how to perform a selection. See articles on `menu` or `choice`.